TypeError: blocker.reset is not a function - useBlocker
I'm using the useBlocker hook to display a custom modal alerting users about unsaved changes. The custom popup successfully triggers when the user attempts to navigate away. After form submission, the user should be redirected to the dashboard, so I'm calling blocker.proceed or blocker.reset to prevent the page from being blocked, but getting following error

TypeError: blocker.reset is not a function

index.js

const blocker = useBlocker(
  ({ currentLocation, nextLocation }) =>
    formData.projectName !== '' &&
    currentLocation.pathname !== nextLocation.pathname
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (createSolutionSpaceRes || createSolutionSpaceErrorRes) {
    blocker?.proceed() // error TypeError: blocker.proceed is not a function 
  }
  return () => {
    blocker?.reset();// error TypeError: blocker.reset is not a function 
  };
}, [createSolutionSpaceRes, createSolutionSpaceErrorRes, blocker]);


I'm following this example react-router-dom useBlocker hook.

Could you replicate the code in https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Got solution, i created function const reset = ()=>blocker?.reset(); and called reset function inside useEffect solved problem.

If you look at the useBlocker type declarations you'll see that blocker.proceed and blocker.reset only exist when blocker.state is "blocked".

declare function useBlocker(
  shouldBlock: boolean | BlockerFunction
): Blocker;

type Blocker =
  | {
      state: "unblocked";
      reset: undefined;   // <-- undefined
      proceed: undefined; // <-- undefined
      location: undefined;
    }
  | {
      state: "blocked";
      reset(): void;      // <-- defined
      proceed(): void;    // <-- defined
      location: Location;
    }
  | {
      state: "proceeding";
      reset: undefined;   // <-- undefined
      proceed: undefined; // <-- undefined
      location: Location;
    };


Note also from that official demo they use a guard clause to ensure that these functions are defined and callable:

  {blocker.state === "blocked" ? (               // <-- guard clause
    <div>
      <p>Are you sure you want to leave?</p>
      <button onClick={() => blocker.proceed()}> // <-- defined
        Proceed
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => blocker.reset()}>   // <-- defined
        Cancel
      </button>
    </div>
  ) : null}


You can either check first that the current blocker.state is "blocked":
useEffect(() => {
  if (createSolutionSpaceRes || createSolutionSpaceErrorRes) {
    if (blocker.state === "blocked") {
      blocker.proceed();
    }
  }

  return () => {
    if (blocker.state === "blocked") {
      blocker.reset();
    }
  };
}, [createSolutionSpaceRes, createSolutionSpaceErrorRes, blocker]);

Or use the Optional Chaining operator on the possibly undefined function call:
useEffect(() => {
  if (createSolutionSpaceRes || createSolutionSpaceErrorRes) {
    blocker.proceed?.();
  }

  return () => {
    blocker.reset?.();
  };
}, [createSolutionSpaceRes, createSolutionSpaceErrorRes, blocker]);

